# Office for Mac is slow, but only on my user profile, not others

Tags: macos, office-for-mac

I have Mac OS X Lion. The Microsoft Office on my profile is extremely slow. I deleted Office and reinstalled it but the performance didn't improve.

I created another user and tried to open the same file from that user account and it worked perfectly. The IT guys told me to transfer these files to new account which I am reluctant to do.

What options do I have here?

Answer (score 2):

The first half of Step 2 of [these instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975725) tells you how to reset the .plist file that controls preferences for your user.  This should have the same affect as moving the documents to a new account.  If that fails you can remove the .plist in Library that affects the whole machine.

> - Quit all Microsoft Office for Mac programs.
> - On the Go menu, click Home.
> - Open Library.
> - Note The Library folder is hidden in MAC OS X Lion. To display this folder, hold down the OPTION key while you click the Go menu.
> - Open the Preferences folder.
> - Look for a file that is named com.microsoft.Word.plist.
> - If you locate the file, move it to the desktop. If you do not locate the file, the program is using the default preferences.
> - If you locate the file and move it to the desktop, start Word, and check whether the problem still occurs. If the problem still occurs,
>     quit Microsoft Word, and restore the file to its original location.
>     Then, go to the next step. If the problem seems to be resolved, you
>     can move the com.microsoft.Word.plist file to the trash.
> - Quit all Microsoft Office for Mac programs.
> - On the Go menu, click Home.
> - Open Library.
> - Note The Library folder is hidden in MAC OS X Lion. To display this folder, hold down the OPTION key while you click the Go menu.
> - Open the Preferences folder.
> - Open the Microsoft folder.
> - Locate the file that is named com.microsoft.Word.prefs.plist.
> - Move the file to the desktop.
> - Start Word, and check whether the problem still occurs. If the problem still occurs, quit Word, and restore the file to its original
>     location. Then, go to the next step. If the problem seems to be
>     resolved, you can move the com.microsoft.Word.prefs.plist file to the
>     trash.
> - On the Go menu, click Home.
> - Open Library.
> - Note The Library folder is hidden in MAC OS X Lion. To display this folder, hold down the OPTION key while you click the Go menu.
> - Open the Application Support folder.
> - Open the Microsoft folder.
> - Open the Office folder.
> - Open the User Templates folder.
> - Locate the file that is named Normal, and move the file to the desktop.
> - Start Word and check whether the problem still occurs. If the problem seems to be resolved, you can move the Normal file to the
>     Trash.